# three.js Having problem with textureloader while using WebGLRenderer & Light

Tags: three.js

I'm having a problem with texture mapping a cube.

I found some solutions that I should not use canvasRenderer and MeshBasicMaterial.

So I'm using a WebGlRenderer, MeshPhongMaterial but the texture still doesn't work.
(I can only see the black side where I load a texture)

This is my code for render

```
const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
function render() {
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
```

And this is my code for light

```
const light = new THREE.PointLight("white", 1, 100);
light.position.set(7, 10, 10);
scene.add(light);
```

And last, this is my code for cube with textureLoader.

```
const loader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
const cube1geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(1, 1, 1);
const textureCube1 = [
  new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({ map: loader.load("cat1.jpg") }),
  new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({ color: "yellow" }),
  new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({ map: loader.load("cat1.jpg") }),
  new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({ color: "yellow" }),
  new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({ color: "yellow" }),
  new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({ color: "yellow" }),
];
//const cube1material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({ color: "yellow" });
const cube1mesh = new THREE.Mesh(cube1geometry, textureCube1);
cube1mesh.position.set(0.0, 0.0, 2.0);
```

[This is my result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G8E9G.png)

Non-textured sides works well, but the textured side is just black!

please ask me if you need another part of the code.

Comment: Please make sure that you app can actually load the texture. Check for HTTP 404 errors in the browser console/network tab. Besides, there is no need to load the same texture (`cat1.jog`) twice. Load it once and apply the texture to both materials.

Comment: Thank you very much. That was the reason!